# Understanding Common Generic Signatures: map

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

The map operation on Stream has the following signature.

```
Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

And the implementation is ::

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> someDoubles = Arrays.asList(2.3, 3.5, 6.8);
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList("dog", "elephant", "peacock");
        List<Manager> mans = Arrays.asList(
                new Manager("John", 100000, 2000, 10, 15),
                new Manager("Steve", 120000, 1998, 2, 17));
        List<Number> numbers =
                //here, type R is Number and word.length() is of type Integer
                words.stream().map(word -> word.length())
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
        numbers.addAll(someDoubles);
                //here, type T is Manager, and Employee is supertype
        numbers.addAll(mans.stream().map((Employee e) -> e.getSalary())
                           .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
```

I don't know how this map procedure works. Can someone please explain about this?

Comment: What specifically do you not understand?

Comment: I didnt understand how words.stream().map(word -> word.length()).collect(Collectors.toList()); is being used in map

Comment: I think you should read about functional programming. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) could be a start.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting confused because "map" has two (at least) meanings in Java. The older meaning is in reference to the interface `java.util.Map`. That's a data structure that stores some sort of value and is indexed by a key. Its signature is (more or less) `interface Map<K,V> {...}`.

The other meaning is new in Java 8. It is the `map()` method on `Stream`. It transforms elements in a `Stream` from one thing into another. In your first example, it first transforms a `Stream` of words into a stream of `Integers` representing the lengths of each of the words. In your second, it transforms a `Stream` of `Employee`s into a stream of `Doubles` representing their salaries.

The example code just shows how various kinds of things can be transformed (or "mapped") to a number.